# MSVC allows using a class in template default before forward declaration

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following minimal example code [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/5Ge6KfWce)

```cpp
// class Foo; // Toggle this line
template <class T=Foo > class Bar;

class Foo {};

template <class T>
class Bar {};
```

With the first line commented out, GCC and Clang both error:

```bash
# GCC output
<source>:2:19: error: 'Foo' does not name a type
    2 | template <class T=Foo > class Bar;
      |                   ^~~
# Clang output
<source>:2:19: error: unknown type name 'Foo'
template <class T=Foo > class Bar;
                  ^
1 error generated.
```

But MSVC does not error. Is this a violation of the standard, or just a more forgiving implementation?

Comment: Why does the first snippet has highlighting set to `rust`?

Comment: Woops, force of habit.

Comment: Looks like a MSVC bug (or non-conformance) to me.

Comment: Try MSVC with `/permissive-`

Comment: @PaulSanders doesn't appear to make a difference on Godbolt, and I don't have the option on my local version of VS

Comment: Seems like MSVC is only looking up the default argument when actually used: https://godbolt.org/z/vYGszn6h9 (which is pretty clearly the wrong thing to do)